# jq slow performance for numerous files

Tags: r, jq

My understanding is that jq can greatly speed up json reads due to the way it actively parses the json stream.  But I'm not seeing anything like this in practice.  Here is a comparison with an R workflow (using dummy data created with R).

```
require(dplyr)
# also requires purrr, stringr, tibble, jsonlite

dir.create('jq-test')
setwd('jq-test')

# dummy data ----------------

dat = stringr::sentences[1:100] |> tibble::enframe(name='id', value = 'sentence') |> 
  mutate(text = purrr::map_chr(id, \(x)c(letters,rep(' ',6))[sample(1:32, 1000, rep=TRUE)] |> paste(collapse='')))

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) jsonlite::write_json(as.list(dat[i,]), paste0(i, '.json'), auto_unbox=TRUE)

fl = list.files(pattern = '.json')

# test read
system.time({
  x = purrr::map_chr(fl, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x)[['sentence']])
  data.frame(x=x) |> write.table(file = 'sentences-r.txt', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
})
```

.. which reports following runtime for the test read stage:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.042   0.030   0.557
```

Now testing with jq in bash:

```
cat /dev/null > sentences-jq.txt
SECONDS=0

for file in $(ls *.json)./; do
    sentence=$(jq ".sentence" $file)
    echo $sentence >> sentences-jq.txt
done

echo runtime ${SECONDS}s
```

.. which reports 5 seconds runtime.  So famously slow R is 10x quicker.  And to rule out the `>>` operation note I get the same runtime for `echo $sentence > /dev/null`.

Am I missing something about how jq works?

Comment: What's the performance of `jq ".sentence" *.json > sentences-jq.txt` ?

Comment: Ah ok that's much quicker - 0.154s.  Still I don't get why loop approach is so very slow.

Comment: Starting `jq` is quite time-consuming. You can notice that by running `time jq . /dev/null` and `time cat /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks. Want to add solution Philippe?

Comment: This isn't frivolous question - the `*.json` approach is still problematic for me as I have too many files for bash to handle - raising `argument list too long` errors.

Comment: As you're in `r`, perhaps `RcppSimdJson::fload(fl, query = "/sentence")` will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something about how jq works?

jq's processing of JSON is usually quite fast (*), but each invocation of jq does have a non-trivial start-up cost, so your `bash` "for" loop is suboptimal, in that a single jq invocation would be sufficient to produce the same result unless the glob expansion fails:

```
jq .sentence *.json
```

If you have difficulties with this, then since you've indicated `ls *.json` works, the following should too:

```
cat *.json | jq .sentence
```

---

(*) At least if the whole JSON document must be read.  For comparison, here are some timings reading a well-known JSON file, jeopardy.json (**):

```
$ time jq length jeopardy.json
216930

user 0m1.266s
sys  0m0.271s

$ time gojq length jeopardy.json
216930

user 0m0.989s
sys  0m0.162s

$ time jaq length < jeopardy.json
216930

user 0m1.406s
sys  0m0.221s

$ time R -f <(echo 'require(jsonlite);x=read_json("jeopardy.json")' )
user 0m2.709s
sys  0m0.463s

$ time python3 <<< "import json; f = open('jeopardy.json'); data=json.load(f); print(len(data))"
216930

user 0m0.693s
sys  0m0.250s

time jj '#' < jeopardy.json 
216930

user 0m0.242s
sys  0m0.102s
```

For certain types of queries, alternatives to jq's standard parser would be faster.  One potentially relevant alternative is jq's own "streaming parser", though it is usually of interest for JSON texts that are too large to fit in memory.

(**) Often named JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json
e.g. at https://github.com/ryanwholey/jeopardy_bot/blob/master/JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json

Answer (score 3):

Running jq (or any program) repetitively can take long time, so we need to reduce the number of calls as much as possible.

For `argument list too long errors`, try this :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "*.json" -exec jq .sentence {} +
```

`find` tries to append as many json files as possible in a single call to `jq`.